# Sharepoint 2010 impersonantion of Global Navigation, webparts and quick launch

Tags: web-part, navigation, user-accounts, impersonation, credentials

In sharepoint 2010, is it possible to impersonante the Global Navigation, Quick Launch and webparts for a certain user? The requirenment that i have is to log in with a user and then this user can imersonante using one of the accounts from a selection of accounts ( these account can seperatly log in with their credentials) and the whole session should be for the chosen account, where as in logged in accoiunt remains same.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to login and impersonate . But need some customization.

Comment: you might have to use Forms authentication : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611083/sharepoint-2010-impersonation-of-user-for-whole-log-in-session

Comment: Nikhil- Please see my comments to Omegacron
 underneath.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question exactly, but if you mean showing a different top nav, left nav, and web parts per user it's probably easiest to use the "Target Audience" functionality on the individual navigation links & web parts. With that, you can use AD groups, SharePoint groups, or even individual usernames to show different content on the same page.

Failing that, I've successfully recreated those components using DVWPs that were designed to look like navigation but really weren't. The content of those DVWPs was then shown or hidden using a combination of security trimming & conditional statements that compared the current site to a matching list item at the root level. In that case, the content was shown dynamically by site rather than user, though.

Comment: I am already using Target audience with AD groups. We have already customized the logic to manage navigation, quick links and webparts based on Target Audience. I was looking for any straight forward approach for this. This requirement is that User A has been assigned USer B,C,D which will have seperate navigation. When User A logs in, A can see B,C,D in a grid and when user name is clicked, whole navigation. QL and webparts show/hide for the clicked user, even though A has logged in, for which sharepoint would automatically manages navigation,QL and webparts based on SPCONTEXT.

Comment: Wow - that's a doozy. Maybe use JQuery to swap out the authenticated user as each one is selected?

Comment: any example to swap out the Authenticated User with JQuery?

Comment: I may be wrong about that - I was thinking the SPServices library for JQuery could swap out IDs on the fly, but it looks like that's only item IDs, not user IDs.